# How to convert times from IST to UTC

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs

I want to display the below times that are in IST (Indian Standard Time) to UTC using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com), the logic that I have difficulty with is :

For example:
**Thursday:** Available from **4:00 AM**, the equivalent UTC time is **10:30 PM** **Wednesday**

[image]

Here is my **JSON object in IST** that I am trying to **convert it to UTC**. Could some one please guide me how I could achieve this.

```
  {
    "Friday" : {
      "available" : 1,
      "times" : [ {
        "endTime" : "1:30 PM",
        "startTime" : "9:00 AM"
      }, {
        "endTime" : "6:00 PM",
        "startTime" : "2:30 PM"
      } ],
      "weekday" : "Friday"
    },
    "Monday" : {
      "available" : 1,
      "times" : [ {
        "endTime" : "1:30 PM",
        "startTime" : "9:00 AM"
      }, {
        "endTime" : "6:00 PM",
        "startTime" : "2:30 PM"
      } ],
      "weekday" : "Monday"
    },
    "Saturday" : {
      "available" : 1,
      "times" : [ {
        "endTime" : "1:30 PM",
        "startTime" : "9:00 AM"
      }, {
        "endTime" : "6:00 PM",
        "startTime" : "2:30 PM"
      } ],
      "weekday" : "Saturday"
    },
    "Sunday" : {
      "available" : 0,
      "times" : [ {
        "endTime" : "1:30 PM",
        "startTime" : "9:00 AM"
      }, {
        "endTime" : "6:00 PM",
        "startTime" : "2:30 PM"
      } ],
      "weekday" : "Sunday"
    },
    "Thursday" : {
      "available" : 1,
      "times" : [ {
        "endTime" : "1:30 PM",
        "startTime" : "4:00 AM"
      }, {
        "endTime" : "6:00 PM",
        "startTime" : "2:30 PM"
      } ],
      "weekday" : "Thursday"
    },
    "Tuesday" : {
      "available" : 1,
      "times" : [ {
        "endTime" : "1:30 PM",
        "startTime" : "9:00 AM"
      }, {
        "endTime" : "6:00 PM",
        "startTime" : "2:30 PM"
      } ],
      "weekday" : "Tuesday"
    },
    "Wednesday" : {
      "available" : 1,
      "times" : [ {
        "endTime" : "1:30 PM",
        "startTime" : "9:00 AM"
      }, {
        "endTime" : "6:00 PM",
        "startTime" : "2:30 PM"
      } ],
      "weekday" : "Wednesday"
    }
  }
```

Comment: As currently written, your question does not show any research effort. 
 Please do not just state your requirements, but show us what you have tried and explain what didn't work or where you got stuck.   Also, be specific, as "IST" has several meanings: `I` might stand for India, Israel, or Ireland - or you might just mean your computer's local time.  We cannot guess for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this using [`moment.utc()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/):

```js
var d = new Date('Mon Jan 01 2018 04:00:00 GMT+0530');
console.log('IST: ',  moment(d).format('hh:mm A'))

var utc = moment.utc(d).format('hh:mm A')
console.log('UTC: ',  utc)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.21.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with Moment, but it can be done easily with pure JavaScript:

```
const ist2utc = (t) => {
  let d = new Date(t);
  d.setHours(d.getHours() - 5);
  d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() - 30);
  return d;
};
```

Example:

```
let x = ist2utc(new Date())
console.log(x.toString())
```

Comment: This is not a good approach.  You are not adjusting the time zone, you are picking a different moment in time.

Comment: No, we don't need and shouldn't to convert timezone. It may affect to the whole system where other scripts are working and other programs are calculating. You just convert the time points between the different reference systems. Don't modify environment or cause side effect.

Comment: That's not what I mean.  The `Date` object is UTC based internally.  You are literally picking a point in time that is 5h30m earlier.